# Allowing parameters to be given in terminal for a C program

Tags: c, linux, parameters, terminal

How does one go about making it a requirement for parameters to be passed while executing a program through a Linux terminal?

This is in C, specifically.

To explain better.. In terminal, I need to be able to run the program
like so

./*program* **FILENAME** *secondParameter*

Also need to return the error message for this if the parameters are not given and then discontinue the program from running.

I can give more info if needed, seems like a pretty straight forward question.

Comment: learn about `main()` syntax  `main(int argc, char* argv[])`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: You mean `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. Or, exactly equivalently but clearer: `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: Look up `argc` and `argv` in the index of your C textbook.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes! , @ Zorca: read 1: [Arguments to main in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176326/arguments-to-main-in-c) 2: [10.2. Arguments to main](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter10/arguments_to_main.html) 3: [Wiki: `main()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function#C_and_C.2B.2B)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple check on `argc` can do what you are looking for:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  if(argc != 3)
  {
    printf("Usage error. Program expects two arguments. \n");
    printf("Usage: ./program FILENAME secondParameter \n");
    exit(1);
  }
/* Rest of your code */

}
```

You need to learn about arguments passing to `main()` in C. `argv[0]` is the program name and hence the condition is `argc != 3` i.e. If you give less than or more than 2 arguments, you'll get usage error.

Comment: Ah okay. It's been a few months since I've written any code so I'm a bit rusty.
Is it possible to use perror() to return an error message generated without me typing out an actual error message? I was told to use perror and errno for errors.

Comment: perror retrieves the details about failure from `errno` from `<errno.h>` about the system call/library call failures. Yours is not such a failure but a user-defined error which won't set any `errno` unless you set it yourself (which I don't recommend for what you do). `perror` can't magically expect  know about a user-defined usage error. So I wouldn't suggest using perror.