# Bad address C (command-line interpreter)

Tags: c, command-line, execve

Here's my code:

```
/* myshell program */

#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 40
#define TRUE 1

char cmd[MAX_LENGTH];
char args[MAX_LENGTH];

void prompt() {
  printf("%s", "Shell: ");
  scanf("%s", cmd);

  char *line = NULL;  
  size_t linecap = 0; 
  ssize_t linelen;  

  if ((linelen = getline(&line, &linecap, stdin)) > 0) {
    strcpy(args, line);
  }  
}


int main(char *envp[]) {
  while (TRUE) {
    prompt();
    if (fork() == 0) {
        execve(cmd, args, envp);
        perror("execv");
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever I input (for example) /bin/ls, I get an error stating "Bad address". I have checked cmd and args and made sure that they receive correct values.

Comment: `envp[]` is never the first argument to `main()`. It should follow `int argc` and `char **argv`.

Comment: Thanks Paul. But this does not solve my problem

Comment: And the `args` parameter to `execve` should be an array of `char *` (like `argv`, etc.), not a single string. The last entry should be `NULL`.

Comment: Show the updated code, with the correct `main` function.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below link:
[Arguments to main in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176326/arguments-to-main-in-c)

The parameters for `main()` are `int argc` and char `*argv[]`

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
```

Comment: But also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321435/is-char-envp-as-a-third-argument-to-main-portable .