# How to use command line arguments in c (OS: Windows)?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I'm unable to make a program that asks the user to input three arguments on the command line: 
1) an operator (+, -, *, /); 
2) an integer (n); 
3) another integer (m). 
The program should thus act as a basic calculator producing the output in this format: .

```
e.g.
operator='+'
n=5
m=6
output: 5+6
        = 11
```

Comment: Do you mean command line as in `program.exe + 2 6` in console or should the program ask the user for input when it starts?

Comment: @szczurcio: In console.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arguments to main in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176326/arguments-to-main-in-c)

Comment: Your question is confusing people. When you say `asks the user to input`, to me it means you want to run the code from the command line not an IDE. Basically it is not passing arguments via `main`, therefore `command-line-arguments` tag need to be removed or you need to rewrite the question to reflect the main purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to take the argument from the command line while the user executes the program you can use the argv vector to fetch the values

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

}
```

So that if you execute your program as follows,

```
./prog + 1 2
```

argv will contain the follwing,

```
argv[0] = 'prog',
argv[1] = '+',
argv[2] = '1',
argv[3] = '2',
```

So that you can fetch each value from `argv` and implement your logic.

Read [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html) tutorial for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in giving arguments while executing the file, i.e. `./executable_name arg1 arg2 arg3` then use

`int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

to get argument from command line. `argc` gives the count of argument(s) passed including the executable name and `argv` is the argument array preserving the order of the input.

You can then compile and run code in command prompt:

`cl filename.c`

`executablename arg1 arg2 arg3`