# How do I pass {} from bash to C?

Tags: bash

For example

```
find -name "*.jpg" -exec myprogram {}
```

Is it from the argument list in `main()`?

Comment: No, in this command `{}` is replaced by result of each match of the `find`. So that your program is invoked as `myprogram foobar.jpg`.

Comment: You are missing `\;`. Your command should be `find -name "*.jpg" -exec myprogram {} \;`

Comment: A better approach should be to build the  command line using `{} +`. Having said that, your question is exceedingly terse. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to pass all the jpg file names as one argument list to your program, you can use xargs

```
find . -name "*.jpg" | xargs myprogram
```

Refer to [Arguments to main in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176326/arguments-to-main-in-c) on how to access these arguments passed to myprogram.

Your version will invoke your program multiple times for each jpg file it finds

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec myprogram '{}' \;
```

You could achieve the same results as xargs if you terminate your find -exec with +

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec myprogram '{}' +
```

Reference: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs

Comment: `find … -print0 | xargs -0 …` if you want it to work with ‘unusual’ filenames.

Comment: Nice. The `{} +` is  used to build the command line.. But, to be fault proof you might need to use `-print0` with the `find` to make each filename null terminated.

Comment: {} + is safe, no need for -print0. -print0 is only needed for | xargs