# how to pass a array though command line in c while argv*[] is a string?

Tags: c, arrays, command-line, command

`int main(int argc, char* argv[])`

In this code argv[] is a string not array so how can i use as a array to perform sum operation?

Comment: You will have to parse the command line arguments yourself to create an array in your C program.

Comment: @DavidBowling can you give me a example to add two numbers through command line?

Comment: atoi(argv[1]) + atoi(argv[2])

Comment: what is atoi... `error atoi is not defined` @sergeyrar

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi

Comment: Thanks dear it works now @sergeyrar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a integer through command line in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160958/passing-a-integer-through-command-line-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 1;
    for(;i<argc;++i)
        sum += atoi(argv[i]);
    printf("%d\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

And the result:

```
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out 1 2 3 4
10
```