# Array access args[0][1]-'0'

Tags: c, arrays, linux

I have searched for any reference to this for quite a bit now but I haven't had any success, so I thought I would ask here. Basically, I am trying to understand a C written program for creating a shell in linux and I am having problems with this piece of code

```
...
else if (args[0][0]-'!'==0){
      int x = args[0][1]-'0';
      int z = args[0][2]-'0';
...
}
```

The `args` is storing the command's entered by the user. For instance, later the address space of the child (parent process reads the commands, child executes them) is replaced using a call to `execvp(args[0], args)`. The definition of args is as follows: `char *args[MAX_LINE/2 +1];`

What I have been having trouble understanding is the ways in which the array is accessed; specifically what is meant by these expressions in this context:
args[0][0]-'!'==0
args[0][1]-'0';
args[0][2]-'0';

Comment: It is an array of arrays, so one index tells you which array to grab, and the other index tells you which element of that array you are grabbing.

Comment: First of all, remember that `char` is just a small `int`. And character constants like `'!'` actually are `int` values. And when a `char` is used in an arithmetic operation it is promoted to an `int`. Now considering all of that, when the first character of the first string in `args` is equal to `'!'`, what do you think will happen when you subtract `'!'`? What will the result be?

Comment: Or shorter, it's just an obfuscated way of saying `if (args[0][0] == '!')`

Comment: The code is examining the first three characters of the first (supposed) string. But `if (args[0][0]-'!'==0)` is a strange way to write `if (args[0][0]  == '!')`

Comment: As for the initializations of `x` and `z`, my first comment should have helped you with that. Looking at an [ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) might also be useful. This is less obfuscated and quite common way to get the integer value of a character digit.

Comment: Lastly, if you want to know what's so special about an initial `'!'` in a command, then you should read more about shells.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you very much, that was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the name of the variable, `args` stands for a list/array of arguments.

`arg[0]` is the first element of that array.
`args[0][0]` is the first character of the first element of that array.

The expression `args[0][0]-'!'==0` checks whether that character is equal to `'!'`.  That could have been written better as `args[0][0] == '!'`.
It's as if instead of using `if ( i == 10 )`, you decide to use `if (i-10 == 0)`.

The next two lines

```
  int x = args[0][1]-'0';
  int z = args[0][2]-'0';
```

expect that the second and third characters of the first argument are digits and extract the decimal values they correspond to. If the first argument is `"!26"`, then `x` will have the value `2` and `z` will have the value `6`.

That logic depends on the guarantee that the encoding used for the characters `'0'` - `'9'` are required to be contiguous.

Comment: To clarify, section 5.2.1 of the C standard guarantees that the characters for `'0'` to `'9`' are contiguous.  It's not dependent on the particular encoding.

Comment: @Bendemann, you are welcome. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `args` is a reference to

```
int main(int argc, char **argv);
```

Then `args[0]` is the name of the program and in the following `args` you would find the Arguments of the Programm, see e.g. [Arguments to main in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176326/arguments-to-main-in-c)

Thus `args[0[0]` is the first character of the name of the program.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but thank you for taking the time to answer.