# Passing values to command line from a function-C language

Tags: c, function, command-line, extract

I am trying to find out how to pass output value of a function into command line in a C file. The name of the variable is "Cext", "Cabs". The default behavior of the program is to create a folder which contains C files in which the output is printed. The code where I have to edit is as follows:

[image]

In the lines 922-925,

```
CCfile=FOpenErr(fname,"w",ONE_POS);
PrintBoth(CCfile,"Cext\t= "GFORM"\nQext\t= "GFORM"\n",Cext,Cext*inv_G);
PrintBoth(CCfile,"Cabs\t= "GFORM"\nQabs\t= "GFORM"\n",Cabs,Cabs*inv_G);
FCloseErr(CCfile,F_CS,ONE_POS);
```

What changes I should make? So i can get the value on the command line and than store it in an array. Any links/ text to read or sample code would be highly appreciated? I have previously looked at these links but i still haven' figured it out

1. [Pass arguments into C program from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498320/pass-arguments-into-c-program-from-command-line)
2. [Arguments to main in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176326/arguments-to-main-in-c)
3. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/
4. https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/command-line-arguments-in-c/

Comment: Post code as text, not as pictures. Also why did someone spam random `restrict` all over this code? Is there a reason or did they just not know the purpose of that keyword?

Comment: I was trying to post it as a  code but i was getting errors

Comment: i got this code from my supervisor

Comment: I think you meant to ask about "Passing values **from** the command line **to** a function-C language". If so, please fix it, by editing your question. Otherwise, it's confusing.

Comment: Break down the problem. What exactly doesn't work for you with command line arguments? Show a [mre], explain what you want to do, and what doesn't work. Don't include anything more than the actual bare minimum.

Comment: @rici no, not from the command line to function, it is the other way around

Comment: when i run this function in a shell, the file is made and the output is printed, I don't want the output in the file but as a variable output, so I can store it in an array

Comment: @Cheatah, I have confusion how and what to write to get a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @hamzah: store it in an array where?

Comment: @HamzahKhan If you don't show any work, I'm just gonna assume you haven't done any. Bye.

Comment: @HamzahKhan: if you want to extract information from a process, why are you listing links which are evidently about sending information to a process . That's good to read about, but it's completely irrelevant to your question. You should try reading the Bash manual, assuming that's the shell you use.

Comment: I found the solution

Comment: i had to write 
strncpy(fname_cs,"dev/null",400), in the code. the above picture i posted was a snippet but in the c file, i wrote these lines and than when ran the script from the shellm transfered the data to a variable before it got deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
strncpy(fname_cs,"dev/null",400)
```

had to write this line of code multiple times in the c file, so nothing is printed and than in the shell, i transferred the data to a variable before it is deleted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).